# How to set the default selected radio button in a group depending on a database value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

html:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="league" value="Bronze">Bronze</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="league" value="Silver">Silver</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="league" value="Gold">Gold</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="league" value="Platinum">Platinum</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="league" value="Diamond">Diamond</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="league" value="Master">Master</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="league" value="Grand Master">Grand Master</label>
```

I have a database column that will save the one they select as a VARCHAR (should I be using something else?). How do I set it up so that the radio button that lines up with what is stored in the database will be selected?

I may also just change this to a drop down menu, but I will still need to know how to set the selected value for that as well.

Here is what I have tried, but it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

```
<?php
     $leagues = array('Bronze', 'Silver', 'Gold', 'Platinum', 'Diamond', 'Master', 'Grand Master');
     foreach ($leagues as $key=>$value) {
          $selected = ($value == $user_data['league'] ? ' selected="selected"' :  '');
          echo '<label><input type="radio" name="league"' . $selected . ' value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</label> ';
     }
?>
```

Comment: Fetch the stored value and store it in the `hidden` and send it to the client and on the `client` `loop` through this `document.getElementsByName("league")` and make the `radio` `checked` if it match the value

Comment: That's looking a lot like javascript, which wouldn't really help me in this case.

Comment: Do you want to save the `radio` `checked` `value` to the `db`?

Comment: Yes. This works already, however when the page reloads the previous selected value is no longer selected, since it isn't being told to.

Comment: Can you post the code that how are you checking the selected value?

Comment: I edited the OP with my php code

Comment: Change `selected="selected"` to `checked="checked"`. It will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the stored value from your db.  What server-side language are you using?

Edit:  added php.

```
<?php
 $leagues = array('Bronze', 'Silver', 'Gold', 'Platinum', 'Diamond', 'Master', 'Grand Master');
 foreach ($leagues as $key=>$value) {
      $selected = ($value == $user_data['league'] ? ' checked="checked"' :  '');
      echo '<label><input type="radio" name="league"' . $selected . ' value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</label> ';
 }
?>

<script>
var value = <? /* Your PHP code to get the stored value from the db...*/ ?>;

/* radioOptions will store the array of radio buttons.*/
var radioOptions = document.getElementsByName("league");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < radioOptions.length; i++) {
    /* Check if the value of the radio option matches the stored value.*/
    if (radioOptions[i] === value) {
        radioOptions[i].checked = true;
        /* No need to check the others.*/
        break;
    }
}    
</script>
```

Comment: I edited the OP with the php I am trying to use right now, which isn't quite working, even though I think it should be..

Comment: @Xzar You're using `selected="selected"` which is wrong. It should be `checked="checked"` if you want that radio to be selected.

Comment: turns out you can just use "checked". Works fine now. I replaced 'selected="selected"' with just 'checked'